# Command line script or utility to prepend elapsed time for each entry in a log file?

Tags: linux, shell, logging, awk, ansible

I'm working with some Ansible logs to find which tasks take up the most time in a particular playbook. Each log line lists the time the event began, in the following format:

```
2015-11-17 14:26:41,643 p=4380…
2015-11-17 14:26:41,716 p=4380…
2015-11-17 14:28:17,449 p=4539…
2015-11-17 14:28:17,449 p=4539…
```

I'm looking for a quick command line utility or script that will prepend (or append) each line with the amount of time that elapsed between one line and the subsequent line.

This seems like it should be an ideal job for Awk. But I'm not sure how in Awk to access a field from the next line. I'm open to any solutions though.

Comment: Instead of trying to look ahead in awk, save the first record; at the second record write out the first with the elapsed time and save the second; at the third record write out the second with the elapsed time and save the third; etc. down the line. Use an `END` block to deal with the last record.

Comment: It's not exactly what your are looking for but I guess a good start point : `awk -F, 'BEGIN{prevDt=0;} {gsub(/[-:]/," ",$1); dt=mktime($1); print (dt-prevDt) " " $0; prevDt=dt;}'  file`

Comment: @Duffydake I think the problem is that you are converting hour:minute:second into a decimal number and subtracting, so what is the meaning of the result? How do you convert your result into a time difference in hours or minutes or seconds from this? If I subtract 6:50:50 from 10:00:00 using your method, I get 34950 or 3:49:50, which is incorrect...

Comment: @isosceleswheel The difference is in seconds (with OP values), so with your example you will get "11350" and not "34950" then if you want to convert it back into days, months, ... you can do it. The problem with that is for the first date and `gsub`  which replace in `$0` which mean you will modify input date.

Answer (score 3):

You can save the last line and then subtract from the following line. I leave it to you to format the times so that you can subtract them properly. Here is the code to subtract line n-1 from line n:

```
# example file:
some_lines.txt
1.50
2.35
7.15
10.20

# awk command:
# for line 1 (FNR==1), take the value $1 into variable n, move to next
# for the remaining lines, subtract the last line = n from the current line = $1
# print the result
$ awk 'FNR==1{n=$1;next}{print $1 - n}{n=$1}' some_lines.txt
0.85
4.8
3.05
```

You will need to format the times, either with awk like the last commenter suggested (but I think that there is a problem here since it combines hours, minutes and seconds and performs a decimal computation), or before when you write to the file, so that subtraction gives a reasonable result.

Answer (score 3):

GNU awk has built-in time functions

```
gawk '
    function to_time(datetime) { 
        n = split(datetime, a, /[- :,]/) 
        timespec = a[1]" "a[2]" "a[3]" "a[4]" "a[5]" "a[6] 
        return mktime(timespec) + a[7]/1000 
    } 
    NR == 1 { 
        t1 = to_time($1" "$2) 
        prev = $0 
        getline 
    } 
    { 
        t2 = to_time($1" "$2)
        printf "%7.3f %s\n", t2-t1, prev
        t1 = t2
        prev = $0
    }
    END {printf "%7s %s\n", "n/a", $0}
'
```

Given your input, this outputs

```
  0.073 2015-11-17 14:26:41,643 p=4380…
 95.733 2015-11-17 14:26:41,716 p=4380…
  0.000 2015-11-17 14:28:17,449 p=4539…
    n/a 2015-11-17 14:28:17,449 p=4539…
```